# Alarm Manager is not working on Android version 9

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-9.0-pie

The app requirement is to trigger an alarm at any specified time and to perform the specified tasks at that particular time.
To achieve this i have made use of `AlarmManager`. But it's not working in Android version 9.

I have used Alarm Manager which is working on Android version 7.0.

I made use of `setInexactRepeating()` method of `AlarmManager`.

I have tried to do it using below code :

`AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);`

I expect that the `AlarmManager` must be triggered at the specified time on Android version 9.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587458/android-p-beta-alarmmanager-notifications-not-working

Comment: Thanks @BackSlash i will go through that link.

Comment: use WorkManager

Comment: @Thunder workmanager is created to respect dose mode, therefore you can't set work manager at specific time

Comment: have you included your reciever in the Manifest?

Comment: @StavroXhardha Yes i have added...with android:enabled="false" and i am enabling it at runtime.

Comment: @StavroXhardha it works on Android 7.0 but not on Android 9....why is it so ?

Comment: try droping `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: @StavroXhardha That didn't worked ! setExact() method worked for me !

Comment: @PrasadKawalekar but setExact won't repeat, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to fix the issue :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
   
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, stopTrackingAtMidnight, PendingIntent);

else
   
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, stopTrackingAtMidnight, PendingIntent);
```

`setExact()` method worked for me !